# Make input field transparent

Tags: css, input, background-image, transparency, input-field

I wanted to take the standard input field and make it look better.
Therefore I use this image as input field on my page:

[image]

To use it on my page, i use this code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="inputstyle" />
```

**CSS**

```
.inputstyle {
padding:7px 10px 5px 10px;
width:251px;
height: 38px;
background: url('images/form_smaller.png') no-repeat 0 center;
border:0;
font-size:14px;
}
```

This is not a problem when the input field is on a white background. But I have the input field on a light green background, and it make the input field look like this:

[image]

**My question is: how do I remove the corners of the original input field to make it look great?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you just need to make the image a transparent gif or png. Photoshop will do that easily, just remove the background layer, make sure your input has a background, and save using file > save for web and devices.

However, I wouldn't recommend going so far as to replace the input with a background image. A simple border-radius will do the job on all modern browsers.